# parallel package very slow initialization when used inside another R package

Tags: r, parallel-processing

For testing purposes, inside my R package I placed the following function:

```
parsetup <- function(){
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(12,type='PSOCK')
  parallel::clusterCall(cl,function() 1+1)
}
```

When I run `mypkg::parsetup()`, it takes ~ 6s to complete.
When I run `parsetup2 <- mypkg:parsetup(); parsetup2()` in the global environment, it takes ~ 6s to complete.
When I run the code definining the parsetup function in the global environment, and then run `parsetup()`, it takes ~ 0.3s

This seems rather silly to me, can anyone explain why and or suggest a workaround? Adding 6s to every function where I want to use parallelisation is pretty frustrating.

edit: Difference in time occurs during the clusterCall, number of cluster nodes created is 12 in each case.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
system code page: 65001

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ctsem_3.4.3    testthat_3.0.2 profvis_0.3.7  Rcpp_1.0.6
```

[image: profvis]

Comment: Odd. Here are a few troubleshooting suggestions: (i) add a `print(cl)` to be sure you're really getting the number of cluster nodes, you're expecting. (ii) add `print(system.time(cl <- parallel::makeCluster(...)))` and `print(system.time(parallel::clusterCall(...)))` to see where the time difference comes from. (iii) profile with **profvis**, e.g. `profvis::profvis(parsetup())`.

Comment: BTW, it's essential that you share your R version and `sessionInfo()` too, e.g. there were major updates to **parallel** in R 4.0.0.

Comment: R 4.0.4, but I also had issues with this kind of thing before R 4.0. The time difference occurs with clusterCall. If I do another clusterCall afterwards, it is very fast, making me think it is some kind of initial setup, as though the node is copying everything in the package or something. Added sessionInfo() to post.

Comment: You can also try creating a skeleton package that contains only the above code, to see if it changes things

Comment: Right. In a new, empty package the timing is fine. In an arbitrary different package (not mine) that is smaller than mine, cloned from github, it still takes 3.5s though.

Comment: Knowing it's `clusterCall()` is a good clue. If you replace it with `parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, 1+1)`, is it still slow?

Comment: No, with clusterEvalQ it's fine, which is weird, because according to the help it "is a convenience function invoking clusterCall". clusterApply and parLapply are both slow...

Comment: "with clusterEvalQ it's fine, which is weird": That's actually what I was after. What I'm suspecting is that the function `fun` in the `clusterCall()` carries along an `environment(fun)` with large objects that takes time to transfer to the workers. However, I don't see how that can happen with `parsetup()` as defined above.  So, to rule out other things, are you truly testing `parsetup()` as-is, or something that it resembles?

Comment: i see. genuinely as is. you could also pick a random r package of decent size and try yourself.

Comment: Ok. Thxs for confirming. See what `my_fcn <- function(...) 1+1; print(utils::ls.str(environment(my_fcn), all.names=TRUE)); parallel::clusterCall(cl, my_fcn)` reports. It'll list what's _actually_ carried along with `my_fcn`.

Comment: That just shows the cluster object...

Comment: Hmm... so, then my hypothesis that you end up bringing over extra objects with the function in the `clusterCall()` was not correct. (It's also what I would expect at first, but weird things happen).  But, I guess that's good news.  I'll keep your issue at the back of my head and if I figure something out, I'll post back here.

Comment: Thanks. I've had this kind of mystery slowdown experience in other 'within function' scenarios using parallel before, it definitely *seems* like data is being shuffled around even though nothing is visible. Unfortunately parallel is the only way (I believe) to maintain specific states on specific workers.

Comment: Last time I had this problem, I solved it by simply replacing the call with a parallel::mclapply. Maybe that works for you? The problem with this is that mclapply does not work on Windows.

Comment: Yes I need it to work on all platforms, the slowdown 'seems' entirely unnecessary...

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a couple of things at play here.
The first one is [environments and their parents](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html#parents).
Depending on the complexity of the function,
a lot of data may have to be sent to the parallel processes.
Take for instance this code that creates some closures:

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2L)

fun_factory <- function(x) { function() { list(x = x, addr = lobstr::obj_addr(x)) } }
fun <- fun_factory(0)

lobstr::obj_addr(environment(fun)$x)
# [1] "0x557ad9605068"

str(parallel::clusterCall(cl, fun))
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ x   : num 0
#   ..$ addr: chr "0x564b16e37e68"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ x   : num 0
#   ..$ addr: chr "0x55a5a9437e68"
```

As you can see, the function is "contained" in an environment that holds `x`,
and when the function is sent to the workers for evaluation,
that environment needs to be "replicated",
which results in copies of `x` with different memory addresses.

You don't see the exact same behavior with `clusterEvalQ` because that function only serializes the code expression
(see also `?base::quote`),
so it won't work directly in this example:

```
#parallel::clusterExport(cl, "fun") # uncomment this to make it work
parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, fun())
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "fun"
```

Functions defined inside packages have a few environments ["surrounding" them](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html#special-environments).
I doubt everything gets serialized for evaluation in the workers,
but I'm not surprised it isn't negligible.
Additionally, when you execute functions that require other packages in the workers,
each worker must load the package for execution,
so you don't want to recreate `cl` all the time.

Some overhead is unavoidable,
but to avoid recreating the "cluster" all the time,
you cloud pass the responsibility of its management to the user,
which for you as a package developer might simplify a few things since you don't have to worry about calling `parallel::stopCluster`.
I personally like the abstractions in [`foreach`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=foreach).
In your package you define functions like:

```
my_par_fun <- function(x) {
    foreach::foreach(x = x) %dopar% {
        x + 1
    }
}
```

And the code will execute sequentially if there's no parallel backend registered.
If the user wants parallelization,
they could install backend packages like [`doParallel`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=doParallel) and call something like

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2L)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
```

*before* calling your package's functions.
Once they're done, they can call `parallel::stopCluster` and `foreach::registerDoSEQ`,
and it all remains transparent to your package code.

And just FYI, when using `foreach`,
you don't need to consume data,
you could do something like:

```
my_par_fun <- function(...) {
    foreach::foreach(i = 1L:foreach::getDoParWorkers()) %dopar% {
        # a very time-consuming task
    }
}
```

That way each worker gets a task,
regardless of how many were created by the user.

Comment: What I still don't understand is why I can't seem to work around this behaviour with some combination of changing environments of functions and evaluating in different environments...

Comment: @Charlie I'm not sure you can avoid it, if I create `cl` in the global env and then run `clusterCall(cl, package:::fun)`, I can see (with `clusterEvalQ(cl, loadedNamespaces())`) that `package` and *all* its dependencies were loaded even though `fun` doesn't explicitly do anything with them.